# Python sqlite3 | как найти строку и 2 ее значение

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть таблица, которая содержит два поля `id` и `tag`, мне нужно сделать поиск по `id` и получить значение другого поля в переменную, как такое можно сделать?

Comment: вводить искомое значение `any_id  = int(input())` и `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='{}'".format(any_id)).fetchone()[1]`

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что у вас есть таблица с 2 полями id и tag, вы в этой таблице ищите опреденное значенние id, но вам надо вывести не первое вхождение, а второе?

Comment: да, это так, мне нужно все именно как вы написали

Comment: читайте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос хотя бы после публикации: `2 ее значение … 2 значения … 2 значение`. делайте скидку на несовершенство читающих ваш вопрос — далеко не все умеют читать мысли и правильно расшифровывать `2` то как `два`, то как `второе` (и правильно их подставить в нужные места). для исправления нажмите [edit]

Comment: Спасибо что подкоректировали вопрос, но все равно хотелось бы полный ответ